# Nuxt JS & WordPress API returning "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js, nuxt.js, wp-api

I'm building a website using the WordPress API for the backend and nuxt.js for the frontend.
I'm having issues displaying the data on my frontend though I keep getting "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Below is my store/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const state = () => ({
    posts: [],
    pages: [],
})

export const mutations = {
    SET_POSTS: (state, posts) => {
        state.posts = posts
    },
    SET_PAGES: (state, pages) => {
        state.pages = pages
    },
}

export const actions = {
    
    async getPages({ state, commit }) {

        if (state.pages.length) return
        
        try {
            let pages = await axios.get(`https://domain.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/pages`).then((res) => res.data)

            pages = pages.map(({ id, slug, title, content, acf }) => ({ id, slug, title, content, acf }))

            commit('SET_PAGES', pages)
            
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('getPages', err)
        }

    },

    async getPosts({ state, commit }) {
        
        if (state.posts.length) return
        
        try {
            
            let posts = await axios.get(`https://domain.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1&per_page=100&_embed=1`).then((res) => res.data)

            posts = posts.map(({ id, slug, title, content, excerpt, acf }) => ({ id, slug, title, content, excerpt, acf }))
            
            commit('SET_POSTS', posts)
 
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('getPosts', err)
        }
    }
}
```

My About.vue view template looks like this

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ about.title.rendered }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'
    
    export default {

        name: 'About',

        computed: {
            ...mapState(['pages']),

            about() {
                return this.pages.find(
                    (page) => page.slug === 'about'
                )
            },

        },
        
        created() {
            this.getPages()
        },

        methods: {
            ...mapActions(['getPages'])
        },
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

I've changed the API URL on here but it does display the data which can be seen here

```
{
"id": 17,
"date": "2020-12-18T11:36:21",
"date_gmt": "2020-12-18T11:36:21",
"guid": {
"rendered": "https://domain.dev/?page_id=17"
},
"modified": "2020-12-18T11:36:42",
"modified_gmt": "2020-12-18T11:36:42",
"slug": "about",
"status": "publish",
"type": "page",
"link": "https://domain.dev/about/",
"title": {
"rendered": "About"
},
"content": {
"rendered": "<p>Nothing much to say!</p>\n",
"protected": false
},
"excerpt": {
"rendered": "<p>Nothing much to say!</p>\n",
"protected": false
},
"author": 1,
"featured_media": 0,
"parent": 0,
"menu_order": 20,
"comment_status": "closed",
"ping_status": "closed",
"template": "",
"meta": [],
"acf": [],
```

Comment: You have `about.title.rendered` in your template, and `about` being `undefined` would cause that exact error.

Comment: @ChrisG I understand that about isn't been defined I just don't get how I define it?

Comment: @ChrisG also just noticed if I go to my homepage "/" then navigate back to about "/about" the page title does load it's only when I refresh the page I get the "undefined" error

Comment: I had similar problem, in the axios response it was everything under `.data`. have you tried to log `data.title`?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet ```created() { this.getPages() console.log(data.title) },``` returns data is not defined

Comment: These requests are async, but your template isn't prepared for `pages` being empty and `about()` therefore not finding anything yet. Try something like `{{ about && about.title.rendered }}`

Comment: @CIB I ment something like `about.data.title`

Answer (score 2):

Use a `computed` defaulting to empty string when `about` or `about.title` are falsy:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

computed: {
  title() {
    return this.about?.title?.rendered || ''
  }
}
```

You have to use a computed here because for some reason Vue doesn't seem to currently support [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in `<template>`s, but it is correctly transpiled when used in component.

Obviously, you can replace `''` with whatever you want to display when the component has no `about` or `about.title` (i.e: `'--'`, `'...'`, etc).